# How to use multiples files for the Meteor server?

Tags: javascript, meteor, import, server

I'm trying to split my server in multiples files, and actually I want to make `cmdb_login.js`  and `main.js`.

The thing is that I don't know and I don't find how to say in `main.js`, use `cmdb_login.js`.

I have tried `import './cmdb_login.js';`

My app structure is:

[image]

If you need the code of the two `.js` files just ask me.

Thank you for the help

Comment: you don't need to include them if both are in server-directory. But both files are in diffetent scope, so main.js won't see cmdb_*.js . Put both in import-directory and try

Comment: I don't need them to see each other, I just need to be able to make call from a client file on `cmd_*.js` and on `main.js` so it should work like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, Meteor [combines all files eagerly](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#load-order), unless they are placed in a path which includes a folder named [`imports`](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#special-directories).

I.e. in your case, your `cmdb_login.js` will be combined (and then executed) before `main.js` in the server JavaScript code.

A proper way is to put almost all your files in an `imports` folder, and explicitly call them in a single `main.js` file (or whatever its name, provided that it is not in an `imports` folder), using an `import` statement like the one you tried (e.g. `import './imports/cmdb_login.js'`).